# How do I compute the Hamiltonian generating the CNOT gate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, hamiltonian, quantum-computer, time-evolution

I have the matrix for the C-Not gate acting in a system of two qbits, $|q_{2}q_{1}\rangle$. In the basis $ \left[ |00\rangle, |10\rangle, |01\rangle, |11\rangle \right]$:

$$
C_{N} = 
\left[
\begin{array}[cccc] \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$

And I have to find an Hamiltonian for which it corresponds to the time evolution operator:

$$
T =  e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}H\Delta t}
$$

I understand that the Quantum Computation operations act on spins, so I imagine that the Hamiltonian I'm looking for will involve the Pauli matrices. But how do I go about calculating an Hamiltonian from this information?

Is there a "general" approach to calculating Hamiltonians from their time evolution operator?

Comment: Take the logarithm.  (Or rather, a logarithm - you just need to make sure it is hermitian.)  Then again, buillding a CNOT through a Hamiltonian is not particularly natural. - You could start with a Hamiltonian for CZ (easier), and then use the relation of CZ and CNOT (also straightforward).

Comment: Thank you for your fast response.

So by following the power series found here: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix), to first order I get:  $log(C_{N}) = C_{N}-I$. Would this be correct?

Just to make sure that there isn't any confusion, I want to find an Hamiltonian from knowing C-Not, not the other way around.

Comment: You can easily do the full power series as CNOT^2=I. In any case, I think the way via CZ is easier.

Comment: Ok, got it, thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't have a specific link right now, but I'm pretty sure this question (or a very similar one) has been asked before in https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com, so you might try to have a look there

Comment: At the time I posted the question, I was a bit in a hurry and despite having searched a bit, I didn't find anything. I recently found this question [link](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15403/what-hamiltonians-generate-hadamard-and-cnot/15405?) that can also be used as additional clarification.